# Angular downgrade from version 5 to version 4

Tags: angular

Can anybody tell how to downgrade the already created angular 5 project to angular 4? I have tried using this command,

```
npm install -g angular-cli@1.4.9
```

But it is showing error,

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: angular-cli@1.4.9
```

Using which command i can downgrade..Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not working....It is showing error

Comment: @shreedevi that duplicate question has the same command AND the same error as your question. If it still doesnt fix your issue, I assume that there is another error. Show it? :)

Answer (score 0):

check  first `ng -v`

and

try to install `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9`

try to understand about [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli)

Comment: Thanks,It is showing like it has downgraded to 1.4 but actually it is not.

Comment: any issue for you?

Comment: No issue sir, Thank U

Comment: you're  welcome  & happy coding